# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while trying to Verify Millions of data

Tags: java, database, file, out-of-memory, java-memory-leaks

From flat file which contain data line by line, my task to be verify data from DB not present I am trying to verify Using Java first I have inserted flat file data into HashSet1 and another Hashset2 For DB data after that I am trying to check Hashset1.Contain(Hashset2) so that I can identify which data is not Present in DB.

Given Below is Dummy Code which you can Assume hashset1(which is some missing data) as File Reader data and hashset2(full data from db) as DB data

but as I mentioned here I have 30 Million Data need to verify, I am able to verify 1 million data through this way but not able to verify 30 million data which is my task. Is there any best way to do this kindly suggest and some sort of code it will we very thankful.

```
public class App 
{

    public static void sampleMethod() {
        Set<Integer> hashset1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> hashset2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i<30000000; i++ ) {
            if(i %50000 != 0) {
                hashset1.add(i);
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        for(int j =0;j<30000000;j++) {
            if(hashset1.contains(j)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(j+" Is Not Present");
                hashset2.add(j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Contain Value Count" + count);  

    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        sampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Error Stack Trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:703)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:662)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
    at com.java.anz.BankingPro.App.sampleMethod(App.java:20)
    at com.java.anz.BankingPro.App.main(App.java:38)
```

Comment: Description of problem is a little bit hard to understand, due to lack of punctuation. Also you might provide an exception stack trace to help other people to check what really happened during app execution.

Comment: @Kamil bhai i have added Stack Trace too now thanks for Suggestion

Comment: You may dump the content of your data file into a temporary table, then use SQL queries for what you want to do .

Comment: I would suggest to read small chunk of data from files in batch and directly verify against DB using JPA/SQL queries. Rather than reading everything at once, since this approach always lead you to Memory issues

Comment: Use a file. A ByteBuffer maybe. Depends on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For combining two sets of data, it's enough to load only the smaller of the two into a hashset (1.), then, as the next step, detect the differences of the sets (2.), and only then modify data according to the found differences (3.). Let's call the small set simply `smallHashSet` in the following pseudo code:

1. load smaller set of data into `smallHashSet`
2. iterate (loop) over entries in bigger set of data, one by one - do not load it all at once, just load one after another and process one at a time:

   2.1. let's say `bigSetEntry` is such an entry from the bigger set, then
   `if (smallHashSet.contains(bigSetEntry)) smallHashSet.remove(bigSetEntry)`.
3. When you are done, then `smallHashSet` contains only the entries which are in the small set, but missing in the big set. And you never needed to load the big set all at once. You can now do something with these differing entries, e.g. add them to the big data file.